# How to capture button press from all HID devices?

Tags: delphi, usb, delphi-2009, hid

I am interested in capturing a button press (or button down/button up) from any available HID device, for assigning a function for that specific button/key, just like most games allow you to assign a certain button for a certain command.

I am using the `TjvHidController`, and have button-presses clearly mapped for the devices I know (Leo Bodnar Sli-M and Sli-Pro), but I have not been able to figure out how to enumerate any other devices and somehow figure out how many buttons they have, and where to find the on/off-bits in the messages and such.

Could somebody please post some sample-code, that "parses" a `THidDevice` and figures out how many buttons it has, and what to look for in it's data-packets ?

Comment: delphi is the only language you are targeting on?

Comment: Well, the project in question is written in Delphi, but I would love to see any kind of sample on how to do this.

Comment: In that case here is what you needed
http://simplehidlibrary.codeplex.com/

I have used HID recently and have been playing around from last 3 months, I have consumend Footpedal HID device in one of my project.